# Use session to hold data

Tags: asp.net, session

I have 3 text boxes where user will enter some value inside it. Then user will click on done button which then it will redirect user to another page and the page will show user what data entered by them before in  label before they hit save button to be saved in db. I would like to use session in this case but the i dont know how. Can someone tell me how? Thank you.

Comment: Um are you sure you don't just want to post your form from the first page to the second page?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at

[ASP.NET Session State Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx)

[How to: Save Values in Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ad7zeeb.aspx)

[How to: Read Values from Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/03sekbw5.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to use session in this case but the i dont know how.

Checkout the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx) on MSDN which talks about the ASP.NET Session. To store something into the session you could use the following:

```
Session["Key1"] = TextBox1.Text;
```

Session["Key2"] = TextBox2.Text;
    Session["Key3"] = TextBox3.Text;

and then when you want to read the values back:

```
string value1 = (string)Session["key1"];
string value2 = (string)Session["key2"];
string value3 = (string)Session["key3"];
```